# Using subprocess to pipe and then write to a file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a python script using subprocess. I would like to get the following bash behaviour...

```
cat input_file.txt | awk '/pattern/' > output_file.txt
```

I wrote this code, but it does not work...

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("cat "+input_file_name),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output_file: = open('output_file.txt','wb')
awk_search = subprocess.run(shlex.split("awk '/pattern/'"),stdin=cat.stdout,stdout=output_file)
```

When I try this step by step in the python terminal things work until I attempt to output to a file.
Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why use `shlex.split()` instead of `["cat", input_file_name]`?

Comment: Is the `:` after `output_file` a typo?

Comment: Did you do `output_file.close()`?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked (after removing the `:`). What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Yes , the additional semicolon is a typo.  The problem is that I get an empty file.